# Overlapping Circular ImageVIew on Custom View

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, design-patterns

I am trying to create a custom view where I want the profile image to be partially overlapping my view. But I am getting this white background and I don't understand how to get rid of it . Setting background as transparent  of the parent View Group doesn't help.

What I want ....
[image]

What I am getting ....
  [image]

My XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:background="#00000000"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/test_image" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#5E5959"
            app:contentPaddingBottom="15dp"
            app:contentPaddingLeft="15dp"
            app:contentPaddingRight="15dp"
            app:contentPaddingTop="15dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="8dp">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mobileNumber_Layout"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:counterEnabled="true"
                    app:counterMaxLength="10">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:hint="Mobile Number"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="10" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/password_Layout"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />
               </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code used to display the component

```
            val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            val view: View = 
            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.signin_layout, null)
            dialogBuilder.setView(view)
            val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
            alert.show()
```

Comment: what is the code used to display this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your dialog initialization and give it a theme

```
val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.MyDialogTheme)
```

in **styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```